# How do I use the patch?

Tags: .net

I'm in .Net Framework 4.8. The latest patch version that was applied to the server is 'KB5034129'.

The patches needed for the vulnerabilities mentioned above are ['KB5030178'](https://support.microsoft.com/help/5030178), ['KB5029647'](https://support.microsoft.com/help/5029647) and ['KB5027536'](https://support.microsoft.com/help/5027536) whereas the patch found on the server is 'KB5034129'.

The question is since the patch installed on the server is of a higher number compared to the patches required, does the installed patch also resolve the vulnerabilities in question or do we need to install each patch separately.

Comment: The web page of the first patch you cited says "cumulative" in the title.  That means it incorporates all of the patches that preceded it.

Comment: I see no "cumulative" in the latest patch [KB5034129](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/january-9-2024-kb5034129-os-build-20348-2227-6958a36f-efaf-4ef5-a576-c5931072a89a). Which patches should I use?  Are they "KB5030178" and "KB5034129"?

Comment: I would read each’s documentation to find out what they include. Increasing numbers don’t mean a thing